# pure virtual class, only 1 derived class, still vtable?

Tags: c++, vtable

my question is rather simple, if you have an pure virtual class (interface) but due the current active build, only 1 derived class is compiled, will there still be a vtable created ?

```
class Foo
{
    virtual void bar() = 0;
}
#if 1
class Foo_1 : public Foo
{
void bar() {cout<<"foo_1";}
}
#else
class Foo_2 : public Foo
{
void bar() {cout<<"foo_2";}
}
#endif
```

their is (as far as I can tell) no need for a vtable in this case.

So will this get optimised or do you still get the overhead of the vtable ?

thx

Comment: Where do you think the pointer to that `virtual` function goes...?

Comment: Say the compiler optimizes something here and now I add a `nasty.cpp` file with `class Nasty : public Foo { void bar() {} };` in it.

Comment: @ R. Martinho Fernandes, you are right with that statement but that is something that is know at compile time... so if their are multiple classes derived from Foo, yes their should be a vtable. but if (like in my case) their is only one, you don't really need it? or do you ?

Comment: @moiself in any case, there's only one way to know that, and that is to compile and see.

Comment: Their is only one vtable per class (not per object), so the memory overhead should not be a concern. Virtual function calls only use the vtable when called through a pointer to the base class, so if you only have one derived class (`Foo_1`) and only objects of `Foo_1` then their is no overhead.

Comment: It is possible for a whole program (link time) optimizer to be able to confirm that there are no other derived classes and elide the vtable. I can't confirm that any compilers actually try to do that; that's a nano-optimization that will typically have no real-world effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll still get the vtable. After all, the compiler doesn't know if class `Foo` will be used in some other translation unit. Or maybe you'll package it up as a library and some other user will derive from `Foo`; again, the compiler doesn't know a priori.

Comment: Translation unit is kind of an obsolete term in times of link time code generation.

Comment: @ConfusedSushi translation unit is the official term. I doubt that counts as obsolete.

Comment: Translation unit has to do something with translation, not with optimization. Optimization is implementation defined and a compiler/linker is a allowed to optimize a vtable away.

Comment: A compiler is only supposed to optimize if it knows that the behavior of the code won't change (other than its performance characteristics, of course). Generally, it must maintain support for anything the standard allows. Granted, many compilers have switches that allow you to go outside of the standard, and it's not inconceivable that a compiler might have an "assume all the classes I know about now are all I'll ever know about" switch, but it shouldn't be enabled by default.

Answer (score 1):

This is a potential **link-time optimization** (but clearly cannot be made at compile-time).

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably get the overhead of the vtable, because classes can always be subclassed (if the contents of your sample code are in a header):

```
class Foo_3 : public Foo_1 {
     void bar() { Foo_1::bar(); ... }
}
```

If all the code is in the same translation unit, the compiler might be able to figure it all out.